# C# Discord Bot Parameter

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have finally successfully updated to discord.NET 1.0 and I'm trying to do a simple echo command, I don't know how to get the message as a string though, any help?

```
[Command("say")]
    private async Task echo()
    {
        string input = message
        context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(input);

    }
```

Comment: Like in 0.9.6 you could do
string input = e.GetArg("parameter");

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as passing arguments into a function, here is an example :

```
[Command("say")]
private async Task echo(string text)
{
    context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(text);
}
```

---

If you would like to get an argument with spaces, you add the `[Remainder]` attribute :

```
[Command("say")]
private async Task echo([Remainder]string text)
{
    context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(text);
}
```

**Note** : Any argument with this attribute has to be last, like an optional argument.

Comment: I Get Stackoverflow exception error whenever i try using parameters. v1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add an argument.

```
    [Command("say")]
    private async Task echo([Remainder]string text)
    {
        context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(text);
    }
```